# How can I check a value in an Excel sheet and match into another?

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

First of all, thank you for you time to help me with this.

I have an Excel (`E1`) sheet filled with info (numbers and names) and I need to fill another Excel (`E2`) sheet with that info.

For example (and because I cannot disclose the info)

I have an Excel (`E1`) with the ID, names, address and phone numbers, and everytime I receive a new `E2` only comes with the ID so I need to fill the info in that new sheet.

How do I speed up that process?

I tried to build a DB with MS Access, but because I am not a coder I had no success.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Exel formula Vlookup() in E2 for each column of info required from E1 to E2
2. In Vlookup() formula in E2, match Id of E2 with ID of E1 and input columnn no to fetch info from E1. See Help on Vlookup()
3. After fetching info to E2, copy and paste as values.